# how to copy multiple pre tag contents with same id to clipboard using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By using similar id's i want to copy to clipboard method without onclick of button.
Is it possible to do this with only id/class?
if possible can any one give me the solution for this method?
i almost tried couple of ways to do this but it doesn't works.

```
  <html>
     <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
   <head>
 <style>
   #tooltip{display: none;position: absolute;cursor: pointer;top:50px;border: solid 1px #eee;background-color:black;padding: 10px;z-index: 1000;color:white;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <span id="mytext">This is Example1</span>
 <span id="mytext">This is Example2</span>
    <input id="copy_btn" type="button" value="copy">
 <div id="tooltip">copied.</div>
 <script>
   var copyBtn = document.querySelector('#copy_btn');
      copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var urlField = document.querySelector('#mytext');
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(urlField);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    }, false);
  </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#copy_btn").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      $("#tooltip").show();
      $("#tooltip").hide(3000);
       });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this. Change from id to class for mytext;

```
var myTextElements = $(".mytext");

var myTextContents = [];
myTextElements.forEach(function(ele,ind){myTextContents.push($(ele).text();)});
```